# How to Remove Write Access from web.config file

Tags: wordpress

I changed the permalinks on my Wordpress site and now it's saying "Permalink structure updated. Remove write access on web.config file now!" which I need to do because the website isn't working now it goes to 404 page

Server: windows

Answer (score -1):

Go to "Setting" => "Permalink" and change the "Common Setting" to the "Custom Structure"
It will fix the problem